# Replace spaces with <br /> on a date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, business-catalyst

I would like to replace the spaces on dateTime rendered text with `<br />` tags.

The code I wrote will do that, except then all of my dates turn into the same date for some reason. I have no idea why this is occurring.

The platform this site is hosted on is Adobe Business Catalyst.

html:

```
<div class="panel callout radius columns small-12 medium-6 large-4 {tag_event month}" data-event-date="{tag_event date (for sorting)}">
    <div class="dateNumber" data-bc-date="format:MMM DD">{tag_event date (for sorting)}</div>
    <span><a href="{tag_itemurl_nolink}">{tag_short title}</a></span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
// If I run this, it will change all the rendered dates into Aug 7
$(".callout").each(function(){
    $(".dateNumber").html($(".dateNumber").html().replace(' ', '<br />'));
});
```

live Page: http://www.blackduckmn.com/calendar

Comment: Do a `forEach` in which you `replace`, `.html()` will get the _HTML_ of the first match

Comment: @PaulS. Could you give me an example of what you mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's API is a bit quirky: Functions like `html` (and `val` and others) that can be both *getters* and *setters* are assymmetrical: When you're *getting*, they give you the value related to the *first* element in the set, but when you're *setting*, they set on *all* of the elements in the set.

In this case, you can pass a function into `html` which will get called for each element:

```
$(".callout .dateNumber").html(function(){
    return $(this).html().replace(' ', '<br />');
    // Or: return this.innerHTML.replace(' ', '<br />');
});
```

When you give [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html) a function, it calls the function for each element and then sets the element's HTML to be whatever you return from the function.

Full Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/lujaq/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="panel callout radius columns small-12 medium-6 large-4">
    <div class="dateNumber" data-bc-date="format:MMM DD">Aug 07</div>
    <span><a href="#">Title here</a></span>
</div>
<div class="panel callout radius columns small-12 medium-6 large-4">
    <div class="dateNumber" data-bc-date="format:MMM DD">May 08</div>
    <span><a href="#">Title here</a></span>
</div>
<div class="panel callout radius columns small-12 medium-6 large-4">
    <div class="dateNumber" data-bc-date="format:MMM DD">Jun 09</div>
    <span><a href="#">Title here</a></span>
</div>
<script>
$(".callout .dateNumber").html(function(){
    return $(this).html().replace(' ', '<br />');
    // Or: return this.innerHTML.replace(' ', '<br />');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Side note: Your `replace` call will only replace the first space. I think that's probably what you want, but if you wanted to replace *all* of the spaces, it would be `.replace(/ /g, '<br />')`.

Comment: It seems that I am having issues now with it trying to replace the spaces right after the <div and before the class keyword on the div tag. Right now it looks like this: `<div<br />`...

Comment: @Phorden: The above will only look at the HTML **inside** the `.dateNumber` `div`. The string it works on will not have the `<div class="dateNumber" data-bc-date="format:MMM DD">` or `</div>` part, just the parts between them. (I very briefly had the wrong selector, maybe you happened to grab the code while it was wrong? I corrected it in seconds, but... In the above, note the selector is `".callout .dateNumber"` -- if that's not what you copied, try again with the fix.)

Comment: I think you are correct about that. I understand how this code should work, but it does not seem to modify it. I do not know if it has to do with the third party plugin moment.js already formatting the date.

Comment: I fixed my version of the example by separating the code from the external JS file. It is working now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul stated, you need to replace the content on each one individually, this should get the results your looking for.

```
$(".callout").each(function(){
    $(".dateNumber").each(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(' ', '<br />'));
    });
});
```